# How to clean dirty test pins in bulk?

Tags: pins, testing, cleaning

Is it possible to clean lots of dirty test pins reliably? We have about 6000 of these test pins and most of them are very dirty. If I cleaned them, what kind of lubricant should I use to relube them? Thanks.

[image: pins]

Comment: I am having some problems imagining an environment where those are used, but nobody being there who knows how to maintain them…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: @LeonHeller: I personally would consider maintenance of electronic test equipment just as within topic as the use of it.

Comment: Are they soldered or can they be removed for cleaning? You could always just replace them all. This looks like a test jig for something that is quite expensive.

Comment: Photo shows that two types of pogos are present. Some are new. Others are worn. Apparently, pogo pins are replaceable. Is this a question of pogo-pin maintenance, or a question of pogo-pin guides/springs maintenance?

Comment: @LeonHeller Why would you want to close such good question? This site is 'electrical engineering' which doesn't just mean 'electronics design'.

Comment: +1 for the nice, clear photo of what appears to be a pretty awesome, niche bit of gear.

Comment: Looks like a well-used cardcage backplane ATE fixture. remove pins, Ultrasonic alcohol bath, bake dry, compressed air https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0ahUKEwiPrf6FmPzRAhVs3IMKHTP3BkYQFghgMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.winwayglobal.com%2FCHT%2FPhotoData%2FField_Application_Guide_of_WinWay_20130408_1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF2wZG8dcu96YmtxCM2obsnI9JB_g&sig2=4gadrOJ9I_06Dgf5mt3Rsw&cad=rja  It's a PITA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test probes are typically a two part assembly. One part is the pogo pin itself and the other is a socket that the pogo pin slides into. The socket part is mounted into the base plate part of the test fixture. Test fixtures are designed this way so that broken or faulty pins can be easily replaced without having to disassemble the whole fixture.

Cleaning contacts can be done by removing them from the fixture. An ultrasonic cleaning unit can be a good way to clean the contacts without physical damage to them. After cleaning you will have to consult with the pogo pin manufacturer to determine if any lubrication is necessary. *(It has been my experience that the platings used on pogo pins and their spring loaded plungers so not inherently require any lubrication)*.

Typical ultrasonic cleaning unit:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are special cleaning mats available that you can cut approximatly the size of the PCB and place into the fixture and close it.

See [ingun test pin cleaning mat](http://www.ingun.it/documenti/Accessori_test_INGUN.pdf) page 116.